# Bluetooth spectre hp x360

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, bluetooth, hp

I hope you're doing well. I recently acquired an HP Spectre x360 with powerful specifications, including an Intel i7 15th generation processor, 32GB of RAM, and a 1TB hard drive. I'm very pleased with the overall performance of the machine; however, I've been experiencing difficulties getting Bluetooth to work on my Ubuntu operating system.

I initially installed Ubuntu 20.04 and then upgraded it to version 22.04. Unfortunately, I have not been successful in activating Bluetooth after trying various solutions I found online. I've attempted to search forums and documentation, but I have yet to find a solution that works for my specific situation.

I would like to request your assistance in resolving this issue. Has anyone experienced something similar with this hardware configuration on Ubuntu 22.04? Is there any additional step I can try to troubleshoot this problem?

Any suggestions or advice you can offer would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to trying different approaches and willing to provide further information about my system if necessary.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
 lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
 [ 0.552991] ACPI: thermal: [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0) 
 [ 0.776729] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: 8F1F6436-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A has zero instances 
 [ 0.776733] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: 8F1F6435-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A has zero instances
 [ 0.776735] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: 7391A661-223A-47DB-A77A-7BE84C60822D has zero instances 
 [ 0.776736] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: [Firmware Info]: DF4E63B6-3BBC-4858-9737-C74F82F821F3 has zero instances 
 [ 1.471039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode failed with error -2
 [ 1.471888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found! 
 [ 1.471957] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check 
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git 
 [ 2.091154] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22 
 [ 2.091177] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family –
 [ 2.091178] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized 
 [ 2.091181] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized 
 [ 2.091182] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized 
 [ 2.091183] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized 
 [ 2.096783] Bluetooth: hci0: Unsupported Intel hw variant (27) 
 [ 2.220431] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 
 [ 2.220434] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast 
 [ 2.220439] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Please edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506950/edit to add the results from terminal and delete the comments

Comment: Now, You can see it! Thank you Jeremy31 to follow the case.

Comment: There are no results for `lsusb`?

Comment: these are the results given by sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Comment: I can not find a solution. The bluetooth does not work, together with the wireless conection and the cound card. Please help me!